# Why does a role shows as "not exist" even when present in the database (asp.net mvc)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to add users to a role when registering a user so i seeded the roles and updated the database with the code below in the migrations.cs class

```
        var RoleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));
        string[] roleNames = { "Admin", "Reviewer", "User" };
        IdentityResult roleResult;
        foreach (var roleName in roleNames)
        {
            if (!RoleManager.RoleExists(roleName))
            {
                roleResult = RoleManager.Create(new IdentityRole(roleName));
            }
        }
```

i tried to fetch the roleNames into a dropdownlist in my accountcontroller class

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
    var model = new RegisterViewModel();
        model.RolesList = new SelectList(_db.Roles, "Id", "Name");

    return View(model);
}

//
// POST: /Account/Register
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser()
        {
            UserName = model.UserName,
            PortalUser = new PortalUser()
            {
                Email = model.Email,
                UserName = model.UserName
            }
        };
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, model.Roleid);                
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "ApplicationReview");
        }
        else
        {
            AddErrors(result);
        }
    }
    model.RolesList = new SelectList(_db.Roles, "Id", "Name");
    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

However the debugger showed an error at this point

> UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, model.Roleid);
>   Role bec759ac-55ca-40f0-a8b8-00de314dd2b3 does not exist.

however this role exist in the database so i'm confused as to what the problem is
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you're looking in the correct database?

Comment: @ragerory im sure cos the user infomation correctly saved in the dbo.AspNetUsers table

Comment: @ibnhamza I have the same problem but I can't resolve it with @ChrisPratt answer. The deference between my code and yours is that I have been created my roles in `Startup.cs` file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second parameter is the string role, as in `"Reviewer"` *not* the id of the role. It's erroring out because there is literally no role with `Name` equal to that GUID.

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn497483(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: Omg!! That was a serious oversight. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: No problem. Logically, you should be able to do it the way you have, but Microsoft treats roles in Identity vastly different than it does other types. I think it's mostly for backwards-compatibility or least providing a familiar API to people who worked with previous iterations of auth in ASP.NET.