# Role ID does not exist when i using dynamic dropdown list

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2, user-roles

I create a dynamic dropdown list with this code :

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Register()
{
    var roles = db.Roles.Select(r => new { RoleID = r.Id, RoleName = r.Name }).ToList();
    ViewBag.Roles = new SelectList(roles, "RoleID", "RoleName");

    return View();
}
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>نقش</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(item => item.UserRoles, ViewBag.Roles as SelectList, "-- Select --")
    </div>
</div>
```

When I select the Role for Register show me this error :

[image]

User is created in table `AspNetUsers` but not in `AspNetUserRoles`.

What is the problem?
/********************************************************************************************/

**Edit**

Model:

[image]

Contoller :

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, HttpPostedFileBase UserPhoto)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            model.DateRegister = DateTime.Now;
            var user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = model.UserName,
                Name = model.Name,
                Family = model.Family,
                PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber,
                Gender = model.Gender,
                BirthDay = model.BirthDay,
                DateRegister = model.DateRegister,
                IsActive = false,
                Email = model.Email
            };

            if (UserPhoto != null)
            {
                UserPhoto = Request.Files[0];
                var ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(UserPhoto.FileName);
                if (ext == ".jpeg" || ext == ".jpg" || ext == ".png")
                {

                    string filename = model.PhoneNumber + ext;
                    UserPhoto.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(@"~/Image/" + filename));
                    user.UserPhoto = filename;
                }
            }

            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {

                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id,model.UserRoles);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: I think you need SelectListItem instead of SelectList.

Comment: it return all role in dropdown list

Comment: Your view in strongly bound to your `ViewModel` class while from Controller action `Register` you are not passing your `ViewModel` to `View`

Comment: update question

Comment: I see your `AddToRoleAsync` method passed `UserRoles` parameter as `RoleId`, not `Name`, thus throwing IOE as "Role doesn't exist". Please show your controller code which includes user roles assignment. For this time, try `ViewBag.Roles = new SelectList(roles, "RoleName", "RoleName");` and pass the DDL value on `AddToRoleAsync` method.

Comment: thank you . it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, `AddToRoleAsync` method requires 2 input parameters: user ID and role name as string, not role GUID.

The main problem is `SelectList` on first `Register` action method passed `RoleID` content for second input parameter instead of `RoleName`, which throwing exception since role GUID certainly doesn't exist for role name when processing `POST` request. Hence, controller code should be changed to pass role name as value on `DropDownListFor`:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Register()
{
    var roles = db.Roles.Select(r => new { RoleID = r.Id, RoleName = r.Name }).ToList();
    ViewBag.Roles = new SelectList(roles, "RoleName", "RoleName");

    return View();
}
```

At this point, `DropDownListFor` ensures that `model.UserRoles` passed with `RoleName` as role name value for role assignment.

References:

[Why does a role shows as "not exist" even when present in the database (asp.net mvc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33015526/why-does-a-role-shows-as-not-exist-even-when-present-in-the-database-asp-net)

UserManagement.AddToRoleAsync = https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn497537(v=vs.108).aspx

SelectList = https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx